# ggplot legend issues: elements overlapping and/or missing? [geom_pointrange, geom_point and geom_segment]

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Using the following data frame and vector:

```
df<-data.frame(time=as.POSIXct(c("2013-04-23 10:00:00","2013-04-23 12:08:00")), 
               info=c("point","point"),
               bin=c("bin length","bin length"),
               upper=c(3.7,1.54),
               lower=c(3.11,1.13),rate=c(3.43,1.33))
deltaTS=df$time[2]-df$time[1]
```

The data.frame can be graph using the following code:

```
ggplot(data=df,aes(x=time+deltaTS*.97,y=rate))+
 geom_pointrange(aes(ymin=lower,ymax=upper,x=time+deltaTS*.97,position="identity"),color="white",show_guide=T)+
 geom_point(size=7,color="white",aes(color=info,fill=info,group=info))+
 geom_point(size=6,color="tomato",aes(color=info,fill=info,group=info))+
 geom_segment(aes(x=time, y=0, xend=time+(deltaTS*.96), yend=0,fill=bin,group=bin), alpha=0.7,color="black",size=3,show_guide=F)+
 geom_segment(aes(x=time+(deltaTS*.01), y=0, xend=time+(deltaTS*.95), yend=0,fill=bin,group=bin), alpha=0.7,color="tomato",size=2,show_guide=T)+
 theme(legend.title = element_text(size=15),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 15),
    plot.title = element_text(size=20),
    strip.text = element_text(size=18),
    axis.title.x = element_text(size=18),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size=19),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 15, colour = 'black', angle = 0),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 15, colour = 'black', angle = 0),
    legend.position = "right",
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#333333"),
    panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "#454545"),
    panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "#454545"))+
 ylim(0,4)+
 scale_x_datetime(lim = c(as.POSIXct("2013-04-23 10:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),as.POSIXct("2013-04-23 14:30:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))+
 xlab("time")+
 ylab("rate")+ ggtitle("Point, Bin Length and 95% CI")
```

The graph's legend can be improved. Specifically, the elements in the legend for `geom_segment()` and `geom_point()` overlap while none of the elements for `geom_pointrange()` are displayed:

[image]

Can "point" and "bin length" icons be separated so they do not overlap while adding the the "confidence interval" to the legend? More specifically, the `geom_segment()` and `geom_point()` elements in the legend should not overlap. The `geom_pointrange()` elements should be displayed in the legend as well. Thanks for any help!

EDIT 9/16/2013: Here's a graph with the sort of legend that I'd like to create:
[image]

Comment: I guess you don't have an answer yet because people don't understand what you want. Well, at least I don't. Could you maybe give an example of what exactly you want, or draw a picture of what it should look like or so?

Comment: @ROLO - added a graph with legend that accomplishes the goal.